# moment.js cannot convert actual month into other format

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap, momentjs

Right now im using the datetimepicker for [bootstrap 4](https://tempusdominus.github.io/bootstrap-4/)

Everything fine so far. I use format `LLLL` to display the date like this 
`"moment().format('LLLL');  // Thursday, May 17, 2018 11:57 AM"`

This is also working.
Now for saving the data in my MySQL database I want to convert it in the YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss format

The funny thing this is normally working good, but as soon I have date of the the actual month it is not working anymore.
Here is the ouput of my function:

```js
a = Donnerstag, 4. Mai 2017 09:00
Zeit Datenbank ist adb: Invalid date
b = Donnerstag, 13. April 2017 09:00
Zeit Datenbank ist bdb: 2017-04-13 09:00:00
```

I have two datetimepickers (a & b). Any idea why converting May is not working?

Edit:
January not working
March not working
May not working
December not working

All other months are working!

Code I'm using:

```
var a=document.getElementById("datetimepicker_start").value;
(to read: a = Donnerstag, 7. Februar 2019 12:53)
var adb = moment(a).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
(to convert: Zeit Datenbank ist adb: 2019-02-07 12:53:00)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to:

- Specify the format of the date you're reading
- Include the necessary locale

Using moment without extra args will parse dates based on a limited number of formats, but you can tell it exactly how to parse the given dates by passing an extra argument.

In your case you're reading German, you can include the German locale from here https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.1/locale/de.js.

e.g.

```js
var a = 'Donnerstag, 4. Mai 2017 09:00'
var adb = moment(a, 'LLLL').format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
console.log(adb);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.1/locale/de.js"></script>
```

To be completely explicit, you can also specify the locale when you're reading a date:

```
moment(a, 'LLLL', 'de');
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  

I was quite sure I also tried this with no luck, but maybe I had any other problem when I tried this... THANK YOU ! Works perfectly!